# sum values with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table test

```
id    Actual     Budget     CA      RUB_ID 
-------------------------------------------
1      20         30        201     902
1      2         330        202     902
1      220       130        207     90
1      21         30        20      12
```

How can get the following result

```
Actual     Budget     CA     
20        130         12
```

I need to do sum Actual if RUB_ID =902 , sum Budget if RUB_ID =90 ,sum CA if RUB_ID =12

```
select 
    id, 
    case 
       when RUB_ID = 902 then sum(Actual) AS Actual 
       else case 
              when RUB_ID = 90 
                then sum(Budget) as Budget 
                else case 
                        when RUB_ID = 12 then sum(CA) as CA 
FROM 
    TEST 
group by 
    id
```

The query does not return what I am looking for , how can I modify it ?

Comment: what *does* your query return?

Comment: `select id, sum(case when rub_id=902 then actual else 0 end) as sum_actual, sum(case when rub_id=90 then budget else 0 end) as sum_budget from test group by id`

Comment: @gloomy.penguin post that as an answer.. not in the comments.

Comment: @paqogomez - it's not really an answer... just a suggestion.  I wasn't entirely sure on what they wanted so I just made it a comment... I don't like having to edit my answers a bunch if I post  too soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your case statements inside the sum functions

```
select
    sum(case when RUB_ID = 902 then Actual else 0 end) Actual,
    sum(case when RUB_ID = 90 then Budget else 0 end) Budget,
    sum(case when RUB_ID = 12 then CA else 0 end) CA
from test where RUB_ID IN (902,90,12)
```

if you want these results by id

```
select
    id,
    sum(case when RUB_ID = 902 then Actual else 0 end) Actual,
    sum(case when RUB_ID = 90 then Budget else 0 end) Budget,
    sum(case when RUB_ID = 12 then CA else 0 end) CA
from test where RUB_ID IN (902,90,12)
group by id
```

Comment: i think you might need to make `then actual` to... `then actual`, `then budget`, `then ca`

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I think you'll find that he has [it right on](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49206/1).  What is missing from that?

Comment: @paqogomez - oh, sorry.  this answer has been updated a few times (within the 5 min window that doesn't show edits), originally, all the case statements ended with `then budget else 0)`.  a few things have been modified since then.  my comment was made for the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    id
    , SUM(CASE RUB_ID WHEN 902 THEN Actual ELSE 0 END) as Actual
    , SUM(CASE RUB_ID WHEN 90 THEN Budget ELSE 0 END) as Budget
    , SUM(CASE RUB_ID WHEN 12 THEN CA ELSE 0 END) as CA
FROM TEST
GROUP BY id
```